# Extract Frozenset items from Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, frozenset

I have the following dataframe:

[image]

And I would like to convert the columns "antecedents" and "consequents" to string, removing the "frozenset({ ... })" format and thus have, for all the rows:

*"VENTOLIN S.INAL200D 100MCG"*, instead of *frozenset({ "VENTOLIN S.INAL200D 100MCG" }).*

I managed to achieve the result with:

```
prod = []

for i in df["antecedents"]:
    prod.append(str(i))

new_set = {x.replace('frozenset', ''
                     ).replace('})', ''
                        ).replace('({', ''
                        ).replace("'", "") for x in prod}
```

Is there a more pythonic solution?

Comment: No, there can be two as well @jezrael

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First convert values to tuples or lists and then use [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
         'antecedents':[frozenset({'aaa', 'bbb'})] * 3 + [frozenset({'nbb'})] * 3,
         'consequents':[frozenset({'ccc'})] * 3 + [frozenset({'nbb', 'ddd'})] * 3,
         'C':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
})
#print (df)

cols = ['antecedents','consequents']
df[cols] = df[cols].applymap(lambda x: tuple(x))
print (df)
  antecedents consequents  C
0  (bbb, aaa)      (ccc,)  1
1  (bbb, aaa)      (ccc,)  3
2  (bbb, aaa)      (ccc,)  5
3      (nbb,)  (nbb, ddd)  7
4      (nbb,)  (nbb, ddd)  1
5      (nbb,)  (nbb, ddd)  0
```

---

```
df1 = (df.explode('antecedents')
         .reset_index(drop=True)
         .explode('consequents')
         .reset_index(drop=True))
print (df1)
   antecedents consequents  C
0          bbb         ccc  1
1          aaa         ccc  1
2          bbb         ccc  3
3          aaa         ccc  3
4          bbb         ccc  5
5          aaa         ccc  5
6          nbb         nbb  7
7          nbb         ddd  7
8          nbb         nbb  1
9          nbb         ddd  1
10         nbb         nbb  0
11         nbb         ddd  0
```

Comment: Can it be reformulated so that if more than one value is present as antecedent, two rows are created (for instance bbb aaa, and aaa aaa)?

Comment: @AlessandroCeccarelli - same is for `consequents` ? Or 2 or more values is only for `antecedents` ?

Comment: same for consequents

Comment: @AlessandroCeccarelli - Anwer was edited for pandas 0.25+

Answer (score 1):

First convert both columns 'antecedents' and 'consequents' to string as:

```
df['antecedents'] = df['antecedents'].astype('string')
df['consequents'] = df['consequents'].astype('string')
```

then remove the prefix "frozenset({" and the suffix "})" from both columns 'antecedents' and 'consequents':

```
df['antecedents'] = df['antecedents'].str.removeprefix("frozenset({")
df['antecedents'] = df['antecedents'].str.removesuffix("})")

df['consequents'] = df['consequents'].str.removeprefix("frozenset({")
df['consequents'] = df['consequents'].str.removesuffix("})")
```